# using filebeat with the logs transferred via rsync

Tags: elasticsearch, rsync, filebeat

If the logs are transferred to one central server using rsync, and filebeat is used to transfer these logs to elasticsearch; Does the filebeat works as expected or does it attempts to send the logline even though the complete logline may not have received? I am not sure how rsync works internally. Your suggestions/advice would be appreciated.